# React Native error no inicializa org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, instalacion

soy nuevo en React Native, Después de la configuración, cuando intento importar una aplicación, aparece ese error.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Verifiqué mi JDK de java (versión 15.0.2) y SKD de android (versión 5.0 lollipop, la misma que mi dispositivo) pero todo parece que está bien. Estoy ejecutando el sistema operativo Windows. ¿Alguien conoce la fuente del error?

Comment: Define que versiòn de JDK y SDK estas usando

Comment: @Jorgesys estoy utilizando la ultima versión de JDK (15.0.2) y la versión SDK de mi dispositivo android (5.0 lollipop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa esta [pregunta de sm_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000729/android-studio-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-runtime-invokerhel), para solucionar el error:

> Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Se debe [instalar Java SDK version 14](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html) o superior, incluso esto necesitarìa que actualices la distribuciòn de gradle que esta definida en:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]